# Review submit is not being done because there is not build

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store-connect, uploading

I have uploaded archived and uploaded my app and updated the information in Itunes yesterday and today i have added the screenshots. everything is ready but this error `Build` has sucked my brain. I dont know why this is happening. Help me to get rid of this.
[image]

**Re-archived error**

[image]

Comment: Add the error screenshot

Comment: ohgh. sorry i forgot........

Comment: have you checked the activity section, is your build visible there?

Comment: @Aakash there is nothing just a message `submit your builds using Xcode 6+ or application loader`

Comment: @Xcodian cause you cant upload with same build number.it says its already build 1.0 is available change bundle version to 1.0.1

Comment: ok then..................

Comment: then it will get upload.it may take a while you can see the process in itunes. and you will get notified via mail too

Comment: is it right to give `1.01` version in itunes @DSDharma

Comment: don't change app version make build version only to 1.0.1

Comment: where is the build version?

Comment: DS Dharma meant to change the Build number and leave the Version as it is

Comment: You will find it in General Tab under Identity Section

Comment: @Xcodian go to general then you can see the last one called build in identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project navigator on xCode, click on general and increase the version number and build number. This usually happens when you've uploaded a build with a version number or build number lower to the one you're uploading now before. And the one you've uploaded earlier is probably not showing because of an error. Check you're email if any were received from iTunes Connect. It might be an error with privacy in your .plist, if you use photos, camera, location, etc..

Comment: no need to increase version.build changing is enough.

Comment: Yes, unless they're trying to update and the same version is already uploaded to the store. :-)

Comment: @RJiryes there is no build version shown in Itunes there is only version number which is set to 1.0

Comment: Yes, but change the build number in XCode. Project settings

Answer (score 1):

Check your all builds available in testFlight, is your latest uploaded build present there?

Comment: Then upload your latest build again using xcode or app loader

Comment: Then your previous build is not uploaded successfully, upload it again.

Comment: Did you uploaded via loader or xcode ? of course you will get mail if any error while uploading to itunes

Comment: @DSDharma did you mean, I should archive again ?

Comment: @PramodKumar  did you mean, I should archive again ?

Comment: yes, archive it again and increase build version too.

Comment: yes i also got yesterday something like invalid build i archived again & uploaded new build to iTunes via application loader it get succeed.

Comment: @PramodKumar is it right to give `1.01` version in itunes

Comment: it means that your binary is already present but may be corrupted during upload, no worry just increase your build version and export it to the .ipa file same like as we do for AddHoc build by selecting AppStore option while exporting and then upload it using application loader. Make you build version as @DS Dharma said 1.0.1
It'll help you defiantly.

Answer (score 1):

Bump the version number and the  build number on Xcode and then archive again. Remember than the iTunes Connect application version you're trying to upload has to be the same as the the Xcode version. So if you bump your app to 1.0.1 on Xcode, be sure to do the same on iTunes Connect. 
Then upload your build on iTunes Connect.
Hope this help.